Tips needed for painting/refurbishing inside surfaces of old garage door
My house is in Southern California. The house is from the late 60s. I am not sure how old the garage door is, but it might be original.
I am in the process of remodeling and repainting the garage to make it more bug-proof and (hopefully) a good, clean space for the kids to do arts and crafts.
The garage door still works okay, but the inside could do with being cleaned up a bit. I'd like to hear any tips or things to avoid. I've never dealt with a garage door before.
I'm aware that when painting it I need to be careful not to get paint in the hinges or joints, or to otherwise seize it up.
The door panels have a thin layer of insulation built in (see picture). There is space for an extra 1/2 inch layer of additional material. I was thinking to add 1/2 inch insulation foam onto the back of each panel, and then potentially paint on top of that.
I'd like to add the additional foam to fill out the spaces and stop bugs and dust gathering in the lips you can see in the pic.
The garage door is sun-facing so I'm also keen to do anything to help it keep heat out in the summer.
I'm planning to make small white blinds for the windows after I've tidied up the rest.


So, are you asking about painting the metal framework? The foam panels you mean to install have a metal foil facing on one side and a plastic facing on the other side, neither of which would be easy to paint...

Yes, I was planning to carefully paint the exposed metal framework. If I can find foam that has a smooth finish (e.g. a vinyl layer) that would work. I only want to paint the foam so its a uniform, smooth surface that looks okay.

Your question isn't clear. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to ask about something specific and technical. We don't do design here.

The previously painted metal framework should be de-glossed (sanded) if it has a gloss/sheen, then thoroughly cleaned from the top down. It could then be repainted with either brush-on or sprayed paint. The unpainted panel hinges could also be primed then painted if desired, but care should be taken not to get paint on the actual moving/pivoting parts.
If additional insulating panels are installed, paintable panels should be selected. The panels referenced by link in the original post are faced with metal foil on one side and plastic on the other, which makes painting them potentially problematic; however, it could be possible with use of a specialty "difficult surface" bonding primer.
